# An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' while retrieving data in entityframe

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have a class called ServiceDayWithEmployee that contains list of other class DaysWithSubCount
here how the both classes look like...

```
public class ServiceDayWithEmployee
        {
            public int shiftID { get; set; }
            public string shiftName { get; set; }
            public int serviceDaysCount { get; set; }
            public List<DaysWithSubCount> days{ get; set; }

        }

        public class DaysWithSubCount
        {
              public int count { get; set; }
              public DateTime date { get; set; }

        }
```

I am tying to run a query to fill ServiceDayWithEmployee from database including the list of day.

I am doing so in a foreach loop like the following...

```
foreach(shift sh in shifts)
            {
                ServiceDayWithEmployee SDE= new ServiceDayWithEmployee();
                SDE.shiftID=sh.id;
                SDE.shiftName=sh.shift_name;
                SDE.days = fleet.subscribtion_dates.Where(x => x.shift.Equals(sh.id)).GroupBy(x => x.date).Select(grp => new DaysWithSubCount { date = grp.Key.Value, count = grp.Count() }).ToList();
                SDE.serviceDaysCount=SDE.days.Count;
                SDEs.Add(SDE);
            }
```

This line of code gives me an exception and if I used var query instead of SDE.days and removed .ToList() it doesn't crash, but I don't know how to fill the days list then.

```
 SDE.days = fleet.subscribtion_dates.Where(x => x.shift.Equals(sh.id)).GroupBy(x => x.date).Select(grp => new DaysWithSubCount { date = grp.Key.Value, count = grp.Count() }).ToList();
```

Here is the exception...

```
An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error sounds like an expression cannot be translated to SQL.

My guess is that the problem lies in `x.shift.Equals(sh.id)` if EF is trying to pull in `x.shift` or `x`, and it would work if ids are directly compared.